# Angular $http post not working with a https url

Tags: php, angularjs, post, https, ionic-framework

In my ionic app I have the following code:

```
    $http({ url: "http://someurl/script.php",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param({param1:$localStorage.test.paramtest})
    }).success(function(data) {

        //console.log(data);
        $scope.data = data;

    }).error(function(data) {
        //console.log("error:" + data);
        alert("error:" + data); 
    })
    .finally(function (data) {
        //console.log("ok:" + data);
        alert("ok:" + data);
    });
```

The code above is working fine and I'm able to post en retrieve data from my database.

When I change the http:// url to a https:// url all of a sudden it is not working anymore. The error function gives me the error "error: null"

When I manually define the id in the php script and run de script with the https url in my browser it is also working.
This is mij script.php code:

```
<?php
//variables 
$id = $_POST["param1"];
//$id = "12047";

// databse connection variables
$hostname = "...";
$username = "...";
$password = "...";
$database = "...";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//echo "Connected successfully<br>";

// show all database entries
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1_id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

    $rows = [];       
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Add all rows to an array
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Json encode the full array
    echo json_encode($rows);

} else {
    //echo "0results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

I have setup my hosting to work with https and installed a SSL certificate on my server.

Comment: can you check device logs for exceptions? and are you using a certificate signed by a known certificate authority (not self signed)?

Comment: @HishamAbdel-Hafez: The certificate is from a known authority. In my xcode console I get the following result if I run the request: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2016-01-11 14:40:33.000 [511:101106] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)

Comment: SSLHandshake exception indicates that your device was not able to establish a secure connection with the server and this happens usually because of the certificate. I'd check these things:

1- Make sure that the certificate authority is trusted in iOS, it should be in this list https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204132
2- Access your server from safari on the device and see if you get any warnings, if you get warnings do not select continue as it will add it to safari only and won't be accessible to all apps on the device

let me know what you find

Comment: @HishamAbdel-Hafez I found out that my hosting provider don't support SSL connection to a database, thanks for the help

Comment: Sure, glad it was solved

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my hosting provider doesn't support SSL database connections in there hosting packages. It appears that this is only possible with dedicated servers.