# Node app not talking to Angular App, SSL Issue

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a node app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It has an Angular frontend and a Node/Express/MongoDB backend. It works perfectly together on localhost (different port for the backend and frontend) and appears to be connecting to the MongoDB database from the AWS server just fine. The AWS logs just show that the server is working and the database is being connected to. No logged errors.

When I try to use the app however I get this error:

```
Http failure response for http://newenvironmentmeanproject-env.eba-cygrd3mp.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/user/register: 0 Unknown Error
```

I can navigate to other routes and NOT get an error if I call it **directly** in the address bar but in the angular app I just get that error, then a CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I suspect a CORS issue, but im unsure how to solve it. Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and an Apache proxy (same issue with nginx).

My CORS in the backend is set up as follows:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.mywebsitelol.org");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
})
```

and a typical call is:

```
 this.http.post<User>(environment.apiUrl+'api/user/register', user)
    .pipe(take(1), tap({
        next: (user: User) => {
            this.saveCredentialsLocally(user);
            // upon signup the token is returned and login is automatic...
            this.handleUserLoggedIn(user);
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }));
```

Im 90% sure its a CORS issue but I am unsure of how to deal with it. This is the first time I have tried to used a node backend on a real webserver!

**Update** + **Update 2**

So I have updated my local version to use the AWS backend and it all works fine, but the version on my online host (hostinger) is not working - so

- My angular deployment to my host **isn't** working with the AWS backend (HTTPS).
- My development build locally **is working** when connected to the AWS backend (HTTP).
- If I just write the API endpoints in the address bar they **do** work (HTTP).
- If I serve the production angular files from the LOCAL node.js backend it **works** (HTTP). (Updated)
- If I serve the production angular files from the AWS node.js backend it **works** (HTTP). (Updated)

Are there any known things I might need to change on a webserver to allow angular http requests to work? The only version of this which doesn't work is the one I deployed to my Hostinger.com webserver.

Looks like its not an AWS problem.

**Update 3**

I uninstalled the SSL from the domain and tried again and it did work this time, so its an SSL issue.

The AWS host is http and the domain I am using is https. Is there any setting I might be needing for the SSL to help it communicate?

Note: I have read around a little and found here ([Angular $http post not working with a https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721978/angular-http-post-not-working-with-a-https-url/35371870)) that some hosts can enable or disable SSL communication, so have messaged my service provider to see if this is the issue.

**Update 4**

My web host says there is nothing they can do on their end, which probably means they dont intentionally block the connection. I could try to get my AWS server on HTTPS but I think that costs money. The other option is to not use SSL to host the site, which I dont think is a good option.

So I need a way to get a HTTP**S** Angular website to communicate with a Node.JS API on a HTTP connection...

**Update 5**

So I asked on the re:Post AWS forums and one user suggested that I need to add a security group to my AWS account and link it to the AWS EB environment I'm using for my backend, so I added an inbound security rule and added it to the instance...

The settings were:

- Type - HTTPS
- Protocol - TCP
- Port Range - 443
- Source - 0.0.0.0/0 (just until it works then I will set to my webhost IP)

But once it was added and reloaded it was the same thing, net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I think its still **refusing** the connection because nothing is happening in the node logs, when it should have output of a login. If it was accepting the connection and then having trouble sending data back there should be some output in the log.

Some have suggested a load balancer but it seems like that might cost money and it would require me to install an SSL certificate on the backend... and it just seems like there should be an easier way :-)

**Update 6 - SSL Information**

My SSL is set up by my host, and I think is a Lets Encrypt SSL certificate. I am afraid I dont know any more than this, or if there is more to know! To set them up I basically clicked on a button in cPanel and it added it :S

**Update 7 - Given up**

AWS was way too much effort for this - I am using Heroku and it seems to work fine :) Thanks to any readers.

Comment: Is your environment variable defined in the production build? Does it still work if you run a production build locally (not Ng serve)? Is it an SSL issue maybe?

Comment: To check I made my production environment and my development environment identical because I thought the same - also checked the fetch requests were going to the right place and they are. Thought it could be an SSL issue but im not sure how to go about fixing that!

Comment: Double checked the production environment works locally and it does, and it also works when hosted from the node.js app I uploaded to AWS.

Comment: It is an SSL issue - do I need to add anything to my DNS records or anything to make it work?

Comment: Using http (not https) in `http://newenvironmentmea` is highly insecure. So its good it does not work. How did you setup your https, ssl certificates? You haven't provided any relevant information regarding that details.

Comment: I have added to the post but its basically Lets Encrypt added via my webhost cPanel. So trying to make the AWS HTTPS is the better option then?

Comment: Thanks for the help but giving up - navigating AWS was way more complex than Heroku, who seem to just use SSL out of the box and it all worked fine and dandy. Thanks for the help!